# Using PHP MySQL query to set locations within Google maps

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I am trying to set location markers. The code below is not looping through the results and displays only the first row. I tested the query and result outside of Google Maps and it work.

```
  var addresses = [

        <?php 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {  
        echo '"'.$row['company'].', '. $row['address'].', ' . $row['city'] . ', ' . $row['state'] .    ', ' .  $row['zip'] .'",'; 

         }
        ?>  
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

```
<?php
...
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  $array[] = array(
    'company'=>$row['company'],
    'address'=>$row['address'],
    'lat'=>$row['latitude'],
    'lng'=>$row['longitude'],
  ); // add what ever cels you need
}
$json_string = json_encode($array);
echo 'var addresses=' . $json_string . ';';
...
?>
```

If you keep having problems, please post the javascript part of the code; this is just the part where you print an object (or array) in a format that javascript can read.